# MySQL 8 - Where MBRContains not using spatial index

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 8.0.29 on both Ubuntu & Windows 10 and I'm stumped as to why this query is running so slow (~15 seconds) and not utilizing the spatial index. I'm using MBRContains almost exactly as described in the MySQL documentation: [11.4.11 Using Spatial Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html). The table `location_coordinate` has 735k rows of `POINT` type lat/long coordinates searching if contained within a `POLYGON` (box).

The query:

```
SELECT long_lat_id, ST_Latitude(long_lat), ST_Longitude(long_lat)
FROM location_coordinate
WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((
        40.79607446677 -73.919978196147, 
        40.70923553323 -73.919978196147, 
        40.70923553323 -74.034611803853, 
        40.79607446677 -74.034611803853, 
        40.79607446677 -73.919978196147))', 4326)
    , long_lat);
```

Explain on the query

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: location_coordinate
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: long_lat
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 735118
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Table Definition and explain

```
CREATE TABLE location_coordinate (
    long_lat_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    long_lat POINT NOT NULL SRID 4326,  
    PRIMARY KEY (long_lat_id),
    SPATIAL INDEX (long_lat)
);


mysql> EXPLAIN location_coordinate;
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type               | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| long_lat_id  | mediumint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| long_lat     | point              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: File a bug report with bugs.mysql.com .  And put a link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Rick James' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720678/mysql-8-where-mbrcontains-not-using-spatial-index?noredirect=1#comment128470237_72720678), I was going to submit a bug report but it turns out this is an acknowledged bug in MySQL 8.0.29

From https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107320

> Documented fix as follows in the MySQL 8.0.31 changelog:
>
> ```
> Upgrading to MySQL 8.0.29 led to issues with existing spatial
> indexes. The root cause of the problem was a change in how
> geographic area computations were performed by the included
> Boost library, which was upgraded to version 1.77.0 in MySQL
> 8.0.29. We fix this by ensuring that we accommodate the new
> method whenever such computations are performed.
> ```
>
> Closed.

A temporary fix is to use the `FORCE INDEX ()` function in the query.  This reduces the query time from 15 seconds to .062 seconds.

```
SELECT long_lat_id, ST_Latitude(long_lat), ST_Longitude(long_lat)
FROM location_coordinate FORCE INDEX(long_lat)
WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON((
        40.79607446677 -73.919978196147, 
        40.70923553323 -73.919978196147, 
        40.70923553323 -74.034611803853, 
        40.79607446677 -74.034611803853, 
        40.79607446677 -73.919978196147))', 4326)
    , long_lat);
```

**Update October 3, 2022:** This bug was fixed in MySQL 8.0.30.

Comment: I have an almost identical table structure and index and was struggling with same problem - FORCE INDEX took my query time from 1.635 seconds to 0.017.  Thanks!